# Bond spreads - SQASW

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bond-yields

I posted this question in the finance/economics arm but someone suggested this would be a more relevant place.

I have attached a photo of a list of bond issuance's in Australia. Could someone please tell me what sqasw means? and how do I find what the value of sqasw is so I can find the total price of the bond? For example when it says BBSW +150 I know the total price of the bond will be around 3.19%.

And secondly does asw have a specific reference to a time period? Ie with BBSW it usually says 3mBBSW, does the same apply for SQ ASW?

[image: enter image descripti1mon here]

Comment: SQASW = Semi-annual quarterly Asset SWap ? If so, then this spread is the difference between semi-annual ytm of bond and quarterly LIBOR.

Comment: How do I know what the semi-annual ytm of the bond is when it hasn't priced yet? Also does that mean the SQ ASW is different for all bonds? How do you know if its cheap or expensive if the value of SQ ASW is dependent on that particular bond?